# Delegate and :not(.myClass) not working together

Tags: jquery, class, delegates, event-handling, click

i want to select all `ul li` items that don't have  `.roundabout-in-focus` class

```
    $("ul").delegate("li.roundabout-in-focus", "click", function() {


        $(this).css({position:'absolute',height:'300px',width:'400px',left:'50px',top:'-50px'});
        $(this).find('img').hide();
        $(this).find('iframe').css({'visibility':'visible'});
});




$("ul").delegate("li:not(.roundabout-in-focus)", "click", function() {
                        /* $('.roundabout-in-focus').css({position:'absolute',height:'300px',width:'400px',left:'120px',top:'-20px'});*/
                        alert('hey');
                        $('.roundabout-in-focus').find('img').show();
                        $('.roundabout-in-focus').find('iframe').css({'visibility':'hidden'});

    });
```

but the alert is never fired (and there are items);

actually, if i:

```
alert($('li:not(.roundabout-in-focus)').length);
```

it outputs: 3

any idea why?

Comment: That should be fine. It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/DQNSb/2/

Comment: posted more code, in my code does't work (the not sentence)

Comment: are you sure the ul element exists before attaching the delegate?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - Still works for me! (I've just copied and pasted your code) http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/DQNSb/4/

Comment: @mr.moses - That doesn't matter, `delegate` is like `live` in that it binds the handler to elements matching the selector now or in the future: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: it binds to any future li in the ul, but if the ul isnt there when the delegate is attached, then i dont think it will work.

Comment: the ul is there. i just don't understand why is this happening...

Comment: @mr.moses - Oh, yeah you're right, sorry, mis-read your comment. Toni - It must be some other part of your code. As shown in that new fiddle, it should work fine :)

Comment: ok, so i will show the whole (incomplete) code: http://toniweb.us/vimeo-like/js/images.htm  ok, you should be seing the alert saying 'hey' when you click into an image wich is not the current (the current is the one in the middle). thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

There might be another handler that is stopping propagation of the event. Try this:

```
$("ul").delegate("li", "click", function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("roundabout-in-focus")) {
        $(this).css({position:'absolute',height:'300px',width:'400px',left:'50px',top:'-50px'});
        $(this).find('img').hide();
        $(this).find('iframe').css({'visibility':'visible'});
    } else {
        /* $('.roundabout-in-focus').css({position:'absolute',height:'300px',width:'400px',left:'120px',top:'-20px'});*/
        alert('hey');
        $('.roundabout-in-focus').find('img').show();
        $('.roundabout-in-focus').find('iframe').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for this go, didn't even thought about it; the problem is that is giving me same result... (there is a mistake in the if sentence -not properly closed- dough) :(

Comment: you where right, there was another handler. i placed 'mousedown' instead and works fine!!